# Adding Google Analytics to Application

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am new to Google Analytics, where trying to integrate google-analytics-v4 into my application

Adding the clasapath in the top-level build.gradle of my application i.e.,

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'

while gradle build running, i am getting the below error

**Execution failed for Task':Ignitor:transformClassessWithJarMergingForArmDebug

> con.android.build.transform.api.TransformException:java.util.zip.ZipException:duplicate entry: org/acra/Acra$1.class**

If I remove the above classpath from build.gradle, application executes smoothly without any issues

I am following the below link for reference of adding Analytics

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

kindly somebody help me to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

This is happening since you might have already added a library which has that mentioned class in it. To resolve check the libraries you have added.

PS Also check the libraries you are adding via dependency in gradle

Comment: there are no other libraries which i added which conflicts with GA lib, eventhough in build.graadle dependency i added only two class paths i.e.,com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0 and com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3